# How to check what type is store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-classic

In ExtJS framework we can define different types of stores. Such as

`Ext.data.BufforedStore`, `Ext.data.ChainedStore`, `Ext.data.Store` etc.

Example store definition:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Admins', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.ChainedStore',
    ...
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;   
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        ...
            alias: 'admins',    
            storeId: 'admins',
            source: 'users'
        ...
    }
})
```

In view configuration of `Ext.grid.Panel` class we must set data source to which the grid / tree is bound.

```
Ext.define('App.view.Grid',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    ...
    id: 'admins-grid',
    store: 'admins',
    ...
});
```

On a some controller, I would like to get information about the type of store defined in this grid. How to do it?

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('admins-grid');
var store = grid.getStore();
//what's next?
```

I've found solution, but is it the best way?

```
var isChained = store instanceof Ext.data.ChainedStore;
```

Comment: This sounds to me like a XY problem. Why do you need this information? What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why would you need to know what kind of store a foreign component uses? Don't like the approach, feels like you're about to hack your own code.

Comment: @thomas At some point I want to reload store in grid, but if store is chained, I can not do that simply by call reload() method. First, I try to check the type of store, and If is chained store I must get source of chained store, then refresh source. I would like to do this (reload data store from grid) universal, for all grids regardless of the store type.

Comment: I see. Been a while that I've used Ext, and only an older version, but I think I'd rather implement the missing/needed methods in `App.store.Admins`. I have not enough experience with ext6 to tell you wether instanceof is the best way, but due to inheritance, I'd worry that this condition would match too many classes. Check [this answer in the Sencha Forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?294993-Chained-Store-load()-undefined&p=1076987&viewfull=1#post1076987) on why ChainedStores don't provide a `load()` method themselves; might give you a different perspective.

Comment: Could you load the store for a grid using `(grid.store.source ? grid.store.source : grid.store).load()`  that should work for all types of stores.

Answer (score 0):

Instanceof is the plain javascript way which should always work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

---

If a store has the source config and no load method it will be most likely a ChainedStore.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/src/ChainedStore.js.html#Ext.data.ChainedStore

If a store has the config buffered and isBufferedStore it will be a buffered store.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/src/BufferedStore.js.html#Ext.data.BufferedStore

---

Depending on your use case i would go the same way Thomas described here already and add to method to your extended chainedStore.